# mySQL: CASE, GROUP and ORDER By

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, case

I have a simple table where I am storing the market cap value for a bunch of stocks.  I am trying to see if I can create a query that will return something like the following:

```
cap_type  type_count
micro     4
small     6
large     1
mega      2
```

I'm not sure how to tweak this query to count the number of cap_types in the different select case group.  Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN market_cap < 10 THEN 'micro' 
    WHEN market_cap >= 10 < 50 THEN 'small' 
    WHEN market_cap >= 50 < 100 THEN 'large' 
    ELSE 'mega' 
END AS cap_type
FROM stocks
GROUP BY CASE
    WHEN market_cap < 10 THEN 'micro' 
    WHEN market_cap >= 10 < 50 THEN 'small' 
    WHEN market_cap >= 50 < 100 THEN 'large' 
    ELSE 'mega' 
    END
ORDER BY cap_type ASC
```

Here's some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `stocks` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stock` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `market_cap` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
INSERT INTO temp (`stock`,`market_cap`) VALUES ('MSFT', 40);
INSERT INTO temp (`stock`,`market_cap`) VALUES ('MINI', 4);
INSERT INTO temp (`stock`,`market_cap`) VALUES ('GOOG', 50);
INSERT INTO temp (`stock`,`market_cap`) VALUES ('F', 90);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following? Or do I understand the problem wrong?

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN market_cap < 10 THEN 'micro' 
    WHEN market_cap >= 10 < 50 THEN 'small' 
    WHEN market_cap >= 50 < 100 THEN 'large' 
    ELSE 'mega' 
  END AS cap_type,
  COUNT(*) as count
FROM stocks
GROUP BY cap_type
ORDER BY cap_type ASC;
```

UPD: your CASE statement contains subtle errors (you missed AND, and the conditions do not make sense, though are formally correct), here is the correct query (matched WHEN conditions stop the processing):

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN market_cap < 10 THEN 'micro' 
    WHEN market_cap < 50 THEN 'small' 
    WHEN market_cap < 100 THEN 'large' 
    ELSE 'mega' 
  END AS cap_type,
  COUNT(*) as count
FROM stocks
GROUP BY cap_type
ORDER BY cap_type ASC;
```

Comment: This did the trick, thank you! Now that I look at the SQL, I can see exactly what the CASE statement is doing and how/where to call other fields.

Comment: @Gunnar, btw, I copied and pasted your CASE statement and it contains errors, I updated the answer foe the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery:

```
SELECT sub.cap_type, COUNT(*) AS type_count
FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN market_cap < 10 THEN 'micro' 
                WHEN market_cap < 50 THEN 'small' 
                WHEN market_cap < 100 THEN 'large' 
                ELSE 'mega' 
           END AS cap_type
    FROM temp
) AS sub  
GROUP BY sub.cap_type
ORDER BY 
CASE sub.cap_type
  WHEN 'micro' THEN 1
  WHEN 'small' THEN 2
  WHEN 'large' THEN 3
  ELSE 4
END;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f8b3/36/0)**</kbd>

or add only `COUNT(*)` to your existsing query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN market_cap < 10 THEN 'micro' 
            WHEN market_cap < 50 THEN 'small' 
            WHEN market_cap < 100 THEN 'large' 
            ELSE 'mega'
       END AS cap_type
       ,COUNT(*) AS type_count
FROM temp
GROUP BY CASE WHEN market_cap < 10 THEN 'micro' 
              WHEN market_cap < 50 THEN 'small' 
              WHEN market_cap < 100 THEN 'large' 
              ELSE 'mega' 
          END
ORDER BY 
CASE cap_type
  WHEN 'micro' THEN 1
  WHEN 'small' THEN 2
  WHEN 'large' THEN 3
  ELSE 4
END
```

---

If you need all groups you can use subquery to list them and `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT sub.cap_type, COUNT(t.market_cap) AS type_count
FROM (SELECT 'micro' AS cap_type
      UNION ALL SELECT 'small'
      UNION ALL SELECT 'large' 
      UNION ALL SELECT 'mega') AS sub
LEFT JOIN temp t
  ON CASE
    WHEN t.market_cap < 10 THEN 'micro' 
    WHEN t.market_cap < 50 THEN 'small' 
    WHEN t.market_cap < 100 THEN 'large' 
    ELSE 'mega' 
    END = sub.cap_type
GROUP BY sub.cap_type
ORDER BY 
  CASE cap_type
    WHEN 'micro' THEN 1
    WHEN 'small' THEN 2
    WHEN 'large' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
  END
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f8b3/37/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╗
║ cap_type  ║ type_count ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║ micro     ║          1 ║
║ small     ║          1 ║
║ large     ║          2 ║
║ mega      ║          0 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN market_cap < 10 THEN 'micro'
    WHEN market_cap >= 10 and market_cap < 50 THEN 'small'
    WHEN market_cap >= 50 and market_cap < 100 THEN 'large'
    ELSE 'mega'
END AS cap_type,
count(*)
FROM stock
GROUP BY CASE
    WHEN market_cap < 10 THEN 'micro'
    WHEN market_cap >= 10 and market_cap < 50 THEN 'small'
    WHEN market_cap >= 50 and market_cap < 100 THEN 'large'
    ELSE 'mega'
END
ORDER BY cap_type ASC;
```

[**SQLFiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e6b1/1)